# Loss data after space in EJS form

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

There is an EJS file with a form, that has a `<select>` drop-down list.

```
   <form action="/scheduler/jobEvent" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="custom-select" id="addJobEvent" name="event[title]">
          <option selected>Select</option>
          <!-- populate personnel list -->
          <% personnelList.forEach(person => { %> 
            <option value=<%- person.title %>><%- person.title %></option>
          <% }) %> 
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save Event</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

The list is filled up dinamically from DB. Click on submit sends form's data to back-end JS file, where it is further processed:

```
router.post('/scheduler/jobEvent', middleware.loggedAsAdmin, async (req,res) => {
    var personTitle = req.body.event.title;
        console.log(personTitle);
});
```

The list itemizes people nicknames, that consist of a given name and the first letter of surname, e.g.
`John H, Mike K`, etc. And I found out that everything in nickname after space is being lost while transmitting from form to back-end. That is `John H` shortens to just `John` when console.log it in JS. Below is my troubleshooting:

1. Nickname is displayed properly with the letter after space on the list when rendering the EJS file, and so all data is transmitted from DB to `<%- person.title %>`.
2. I hardcoded nickname in the list, i.e. `<option value='John H'><%- person.title %></option>` and it comes to the back-end file in the same way, and so nothing loses between client and server-side.
3. I added underscore in nicknames in the DB, i.e. `John_H` and it works as it should be without losses, that is it relates somehow to space.
   Has anyone encountered such an issue?
   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the working and non-working code:

> ```
> <option value=<%- person.title %>>
> ```

and

> ```
> <option value='John H'>
> ```

What is different?

**quotes**

If you don't have quotes around an attribute value, then a space **ends the value** and whatever comes after the space starts a **new attribute**.